# Derivative of an exact form $\omega_t$ is still exact?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\omega_t$ be an exact form depending smoothly on time $t$.

Then is $\dfrac{d\omega_t}{dt}$ also exact?

$\dfrac{\omega_t - \omega_{t_0}}{t-t_0}$ is clearly exact.

However I am stuck in showing that its limit is exact.

Thanks in advance.

**Using Ted's hint**

Let $c$ be an any smooth k-cycle. Since $\omega_t$ is exact, $\displaystyle\int_c \omega_t =0$

It suffices to prove that $\displaystyle\int_c \lim_{t \to t_0} \dfrac{\omega_t - \omega_{t_0}}{t-t_0} = \lim_{t \to t_0}\displaystyle\int_c \dfrac{\omega_t - \omega_{t_0}}{t-t_0} $.

However this is on the world of manifolds and diffenretial forms, I am not sure it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: A closed $k$-form is exact if and only if its integral over every $k$-cycle is zero. (Comment: The [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for differentiating under the integral sign applies to manifolds as well, giving 
$$\frac d{dt} \int_M \omega = \int_M \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial t}.$$
The "nice" proof using dominated convergence works just as for one-dimensional integrals.)

Comment: I have tired it by using your hint. As above, however, I am stuck again. Could you give me another hints about my obstacles?

Comment: @Jeong: You are on the right track. I added a comment for you.

Comment: Really, there's nothing more going on here than the fact that we're working in a Frechet space (though you could work in Banach if you like): $\omega_t$ always lies in the closed subspace of exact forms, and therefore its derivative does too. The nontrivial part of this statement is that the space of exact forms is closed. You give an explicit set of functionals whose zero set is the space of exact forms; the only other proof I can think of right now uses eg Hodge theory.

Comment: It would also suffice to prove that any 1-parameter family of exact forms has a 1-parameter family of derivatives $\mu_t$. From there the result immediately follows.

Answer (score -1):

An exact form is a differential form $\omega$ such that $\omega = df$ for some differential form $f$. Then $\frac{d\omega_{t}}{dt}$ is exact as it is the derivative of $\omega$.

Comment: My question is in the process of proving that the exactness of $\omega_t$ implies the existence of **smooth** $\mu_t$ such that $\omega_t = d \mu_t$. So I should not use the fact.

Comment: Ahhh, my fault I misunderstood. I'll think on that then.

Comment: @Kit: I don't see how to salvage this.